# Load Application On Startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, chromium

I am using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian to power a reception screen, which is just a simple web page running fullscreen.

I would like this screen to load whenever the machine is booted, so that if the machine is reset after a powercut etc it will automatically load back up again.

How do I go about setting the web browser (Chromium) to load on bootup?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest answer would probably be a cron job with a @reboot flag.

Run the command: `crontab -e` and at the bottom add `@reboot my important command here`.

If you're looking at something more complex you'll definitely want to look at creating a full on init script, but for your purposes I think cron should be good enough.